# How to find USB thumbdrive volume on PC booted from Easy Recovery Essentials?

Tags: linux, windows-7, boot

My PC (Windows 7) was having a problem and I'm using https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/ to try to fix it. It seems to be a minimal Linux-like OS that boots and lets you get files off the native file system on the hard drive. I've got it booted and found the files I need to rescue, but I can't seem to figure out where to put them. I put in a thumbdrive and want to copy the files to it, but I don't see it anywhere on the file system tree that Easy Recovery Essentials is showing me. Anyone know how to make this work - where would I find the USB thumbdrive as a destination volume? I've emailed their tech support but no response yet.

Comment: You are following the instructions in [https://neosmart.net/wiki/easyre/recovery/](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easyre/recovery), right? Can you perhaps point out the step you're having trouble with?

Comment: I followed the recovery step and it failed. The next step is to reinstall from scratch, but first I am trying to save a few files off the drive. I can see the files in this GUI, but I can't figure out how to get them off the disk - my USB thumbdrive seems to be nowhere on their file system tree.